# I am looking for a cartoon, old one, with virtual reality?

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

I am getting nostalgic memories about a cartoon/anime that was in the tv when I was a kid, approximately 17 years ago.  However lately I was thinking about it a lot and it got my attention, I would love to find out about it.

I only have some some scattered memories so I apologize for that.

They were kids/teenagers and they were using some sort of "hover boards" , which looked like two circles, one for each leg.

They were entering some kind of portals, they were always purple and in the shape of cube. The portals always came down from the sky. There was also "announcer" voice, saying when and where the next portal will be. They called the portals  "games". The announcer always said something like "The game is starting in 10, 9, 8..."

In order to enter the "game", they had to stand underneath the falling purple cube. Once it landed, nobody else was able to enter, I think.

I do not remember what was their objective inside or the point of going inside the portals.

Also, they used some kind of flying object , I think it was in the shape of yellowish fish. In order to control it like steer etc. they had to press bunch of buttons in order to do it.

Comment: Is this *ReBoot*?

Comment: Yes thank yooou!

Answer (score 74):

The "incoming game" motif - especially the description as purplish blocks - reminds me a great deal of [*ReBoot*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReBoot) (1994) [(link on IMDb)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108903/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1).  I'm pretty sure Enzo had a flying board like you describe (and maybe one for Frisket too).

This is what the incoming games looked like:

[image: Warning: incoming game!]

Incoming games, and other important system events (system crash, incoming file/data) were announced by the "[System Voice](https://reboot.fandom.com/wiki/System_Voice)".

And a view of AndrAIa, Matrix, Enzo and Bob on zip boards:

[image: AndrAIa, Matrix, Enzo and Bob on zip boards]

Comment: Oh my gosh yes that it hahaha thanks ! Gotta watch this ! So much nostalgia....

Comment: @Pokoloko Please accept this answer using the checkmark under the voting arrows; it will let other people searching know that this question might help them.

Comment: Good news, there may be an easy way to stream this one online: https://www.shoutfactorytv.com/series/reboot

Comment: omg how cheesy it looks! I remember it much more sharper, crispy and futuristic than it actually is. Weird.